# python-docx - Lists showing up as normal paragraphs

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to insert numeric and bulleted lists into an existing Word document, however they are showing up as normal paragraphs:

```
# Open up existing document
document = Document('existing_document.docx')

# Add style from example document
temp_doc = Document()
document.styles.add_style('List Number', temp_doc.styles['List Number'].type)

# Add bullet points from example document
p = document.add_paragraph()
p.style = 'List Number'
p.add_run('Item 1')
p = document.add_paragraph()
p.style = 'List Number'
p.add_run('Item 2')

# Save
document.save('new_doc_with_list.docx')
```

This results in 3 paragraphs. No indenting or numbering.

I have also tried to set up all the attributes the same, and then complete the runs, however this does not work either:

```
document.styles['List Number'].base_style = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].base_style
document.styles['List Number'].next_paragraph_style = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].next_paragraph_style
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.alignment = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.alignment
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.first_line_indent = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.first_line_indent
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.keep_together = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.keep_together
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.keep_with_next = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.keep_with_next
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.left_indent = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.left_indent
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.line_spacing = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.line_spacing
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.line_spacing_rule = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.line_spacing_rule
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.page_break_before = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.page_break_before
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.right_indent = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.right_indent
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.space_after = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.space_after
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.space_before = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.space_before
document.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.widow_control = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].paragraph_format.widow_control
document.styles['List Number'].priority = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].priority
document.styles['List Number'].locked = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].locked
document.styles['List Number'].font.all_caps = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.all_caps
document.styles['List Number'].font.bold = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.bold
document.styles['List Number'].font.complex_script = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.complex_script
document.styles['List Number'].font.cs_bold = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.cs_bold
document.styles['List Number'].font.cs_italic = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.cs_italic
document.styles['List Number'].font.double_strike = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.double_strike
document.styles['List Number'].font.emboss = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.emboss
document.styles['List Number'].font.hidden = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.hidden
document.styles['List Number'].font.imprint = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.imprint
document.styles['List Number'].font.italic = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.italic
document.styles['List Number'].font.math = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.math
document.styles['List Number'].font.name = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.name
document.styles['List Number'].font.no_proof = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.no_proof
document.styles['List Number'].font.outline = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.outline
document.styles['List Number'].font.rtl = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.rtl
document.styles['List Number'].font.shadow = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.shadow
document.styles['List Number'].font.size = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.size
document.styles['List Number'].font.small_caps = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.small_caps
document.styles['List Number'].font.snap_to_grid = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.snap_to_grid
document.styles['List Number'].font.spec_vanish = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.spec_vanish
document.styles['List Number'].font.strike = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.strike
document.styles['List Number'].font.subscript = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.subscript
document.styles['List Number'].font.superscript = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.superscript
document.styles['List Number'].font.underline = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.underline
document.styles['List Number'].font.web_hidden = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].font.web_hidden
document.styles['List Number'].quick_style = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].quick_style
document.styles['List Number'].style_id = temp_doc.styles['List Number'].style_id
```

Did I miss anything for indenting or numbering? I'd also be interested in learning how to do this for an unordered list too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bulleted and Numbered lists in Word are more complicated than other styles. They need to be linked to a numbering format, which is quite complex in itself, and not yet supported at the API level in python-docx.

If you can use a "template" document as a starting point that has the list styles you need already defined, that will work, but of course that's not suitable for every use case.

Answer (score 2):

I have not be able to find a solution that worked for my problem that was similar to this by editing or working with the styles and I do not understand why lists follow the formatting for paragraphs. I think they should have there own. Either way, I created a class that works around the issue and builds the list I want them. It is not perfect and I am sure that others can really improve what I have done, but I thought I would share.

```
import docx

class Paragraph_List(object):
    def __init__(self,*args): #args are: doc,item1,ordered,style,fmt (style and fmt optional)
        self.args = args
        self.doc =self.args[0]
        self.item1 = self.args[1]
        self.ordered = self.args[2]
        self.place = {}
        List_dict = {'Roman':[['I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IIX','IX','X'],['A','B','C','D','E','F',
            'G','H','I','J','K','L'],['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h',
            'i'],['i','ii','iii','iv','v','vi','vii','viii','iix','ix','x']],'ABC':[['A','B','C','D','E','F','G',
            'H','I','J','K','L'],['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'],
            ['i','ii','iii','iv','v','vi','vii','viii','iix','ix','x']],'123':[['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'
            ],['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'],['i','ii','iii','iv','v','vi','vii','viii','iix','ix','x']],'Bullet':[
            ['●','○','•','◦']]}
        if self.ordered == True:
            if len(self.args) < 4:
                self.fmt = List_dict['Roman']
            elif self.args[3] == 'Custom':
                self.fmt = self.args[4]
            else:
                self.fmt = List_dict[self.args[3]]
            self.p = self.doc.add_paragraph(self.fmt[0][0]+'. ' + self.item1 + '\n')
        else:
            self.fmt = List_dict['Bullet']
            self.p = self.doc.add_paragraph(self.fmt[0][0]+ ' ' + self.item1 + '\n')
        # self.doc.add_paragraph(item1, style=self.level)

    def add_item(self, item, level):
        self.level = level
        self.place[1] = 0
        if self.level ==1:
            sp = ""
        else:
            sp = "    "
            sp = sp *(self.level -1)
        if self.level in self.place:
            self.place[self.level] += 1
        else:
            self.place[self.level] = 0
        if self.ordered ==True:
            self.p.add_run(sp + self.fmt[self.level - 1][self.place[self.level]] + '. ' + item + '\n')
        else:
            self.p.add_run(sp + self.fmt[0][self.level - 1]+ ' ' + item + '\n')


#Main Body==================================================================================================


document = docx.Document()
mylist = Paragraph_List(document, 'item 1', True)
mylist.add_item('Level 2 Item 1',2)
mylist.add_item('Level 2 Item 2',2)
mylist.add_item('Level 2 Item 3',2)
mylist.add_item('Level 3 Item 1',3)
mylist.add_item('Level 3 Item 2',3)
mylist.add_item('Level 3 Item 3',3)
mylist.add_item('Level 3 Item 4',3)
mylist.add_item('Level 3 Item 5',3)
mylist.add_item('Level 1 Item 2',1)

mylist2 = Paragraph_List(document, 'Bullet Level 1 Item 1', False)
mylist2.add_item('Level 1 Item2',1)
mylist2.add_item('Level 2 Item1',2)
mylist2.add_item('Level 1 Item3',1)
mylist2.add_item('Level 2 Item1',2)
mylist2.add_item('Level 2 Item2',2)
mylist2.add_item('Level 2 Item3',2)
mylist2.add_item('Level 3 Item1',3)
mylist2.add_item('Level 4 Item1',4)
mylist2.add_item('Level 4 Item2',4)
mylist2.add_item('Level 2 Item4',2)

document.save('new.docx')
```