# Using python-docx to to read .docx, preserving special characters, bullets

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to batch manipulate many microsoft word documents in .docx format within python.

The following code accomplishes what I need, except it loses special characters I would like to preserve, like the right arrow symbol and bullets.

```
import docx

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return fullText

getText('example.docx')
```

Comment: Seems like [bullets are not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158991/python-docx-lists-showing-up-as-normal-paragraphs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Paragraph.text` property in `python-pptx` returns the plain text in the paragraph as a string. This is a very common requirement.

Bullets, or numbered lists in general (of which bullets are a type) are not reflected in the text of a paragraph, even though it may appear that way on-screen. This sort of thing will be an additional property of the paragraph.

One way bullets can be applied is using the 'List Bullet' style. The paragraph style is available on `Paragraph.style`.

The documentation here is your friend for this and other details, in particular the 11 topics in the User Guide section:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/