# how to extract formatted data from docx file using python

Tags: python, docx

Example:
I have docx file with very similar content as below

> Introduction
>
> A. This is text
>
> 1. This is second text
>
>    1.1 more complex st
> 2. Yes it is
>
> I. Now Roman

I want to store the output in a json data structure. Out for above should be

Output

> {'A': 'This is text', '1': 'This is second text', '1.1': 'more complex
>   st', '2': 'Yes it is', 'I': 'Now Roman'}

my current code is

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('myDoc.docx')

for para in document.paragraphs:
    print para.text
```

But the problem with this code is para.text not containing paragraph number. it is only containing paragraph content.
Example 
For paragraph "A. This is text", para.text containing only "This is text" but I want "A. This is text".

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: @user2314737 Sorry, I have recently started using StackOverflow. I will improve my way of asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the python-docx module

Read the data like this:

```
from docx import Document


document = Document('test.docx')

for para in document.paragraphs:
    print para.text
```

Once you have the data, you can build your dictionary

Comment: Hi, But by this approach para.text has only paragraph text, not paragraph number like for paragraph                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "3.1 The Employee’s total remuneration is set out" para.text has only "The Employee’s total remuneration is set out" not 3.1 because of indentation I think

Comment: Refer to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158991/python-docx-lists-showing-up-as-normal-paragraphs, I think what you want to do is not supported. You could consider converting it to a simple text file and reading it that way

Answer (score 0):

First, convert Doc/Word into HTML using add-ins (https://github.com/thepankajsingh/extract-doc-add-ins). Now you can easily parse HTML to get key-value pair.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using this. It's licensed by Microsoft (see app.js in Github repo). If it was an Apache or MIT license you would be good to go, but this code belongs to someone and it doesn't look like they're sharing.